# ReferenceError: React is not defined with Parcel Bundler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parceljs

I am following this [Article](https://tekinico.medium.com/build-a-react-embeddable-widget-c46b7f7999d8) to bundle my react app as a single js file that can be embedded as a widget into any website

Here is a redacted version of my `package.json` file showcasing the build scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:widget": "parcel build src/index.js --no-source-maps -d widget" //This
  }
```

So, on running `yarn build:widget`, I want parcel to build the entire App into a single `index.js` file that I can embed in a regular html file.

The build worked, but the only issue now is that I am getting the error `ReferenceError: React is not defined` after referencing the output `index.js` file inside my `index.html` file as shown below

```
<body>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <div id="widget-section"></div>
</body>
<link href="../index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../index.js"></script> //ReferenceError: React is not defined gets thrown here
```

Is there a better work around to this?

Answer (score 0):

Even if your JavaScript does not explicitly call `React` i.e. `import React from "react"`, you still need to add this import if you are using JSX. This is due to your JSX transpiler inlining JSX as `React.createElement` calls.

Comment: No unfortunately that wasn't the issue. The issue was that I indeed forgot to import React into the component. It turns out that within React itself, React was implicitly importing React for me so the error was not coming up during development. It was when I tried building with Parcel that it started throwing errors. After I imported React everything worked well.

Comment: I have updated the answer to isolate the true problem and provide additional information regarding the failure scenario.